# Memory Issues, CGI, User Switching

Tags: apache-2.2, php, fastcgi

Okay so the situation is as follows: I have a small cloud VPS that has 256mb of RAM, one of my 'heavier' websites was causing apache to use more and go into deep swap usage.

I have now tweaked down apache and it stays stable at around 200mb's of ram (server wide), still apache uses a lot of memory and I'd like to decrease this.

I have been running apache with mod_ruid for automatically switching to whatever user owns a specific file, this works fine in combination with PHP.

Now I want to switch to FastCGI or something similar to be able to possibly switch to a threaded apache MPM and decrease memory usage, however I have some questions:

- Is there anything similar to mod_ruid for PHP-FPM
- Are there any examples/tutorials on how to configure PHP-FPM with Apache and something mod-ruid-ish

I tried configuring PHP-FPM but it somehow got enabled for all the files in the webroot and just gave WSODs (Wordpress Install), I suspect configuration was wrong, but before continuing to figure it out I'd prefer to know if what I want is even remotely possible.

Thanks, Xeross

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No there isn't anything available
   similar to mod_ruid, you need a
   seperate pool per user/group
2. Didn't figure this one out, switched to nginx+PHP-FPM

Memory usage is down quite a lot so I'd say this is solved, just hope PHP-FPM will someday implement something similar to mod_ruid